# COM port connection to cnc machine

Tags: hardware

Running dual boot Windows 10/Ubuntu 23.10 on a Dell Optiplex desktop.
Trying to use CNCjs or gSender to connect to a cnc machine with a USB connection.
Connects automatically with the same apps in Windows 10 and 11.
The apps do not recognize the COM ports in Ubuntu, and will not connect to machine.
What, if any, is the correction for this problem?
Any help would be appreciated, as I would rather run the machine from linux than windows/

Comment: Linux doesn't have COM ports, we have entries in the `/dev/` tree. Look at your system startup log (watch your kernel discover the hardware) with the terminal command `sudo journalctl  -b 0`. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: OK, did that.  Not a hardware person, not sure what I am looking for.  Just need a way for gSender or CNCjs to be able to connect, through a USB port, to the cnc controller.

Comment: lsusb shows device as Nomad 3 (this is correct) on USB hub 3, port changes when device is turned off and back on.  There are NO tty entries under /dev or anywhere, USB is under /dev/bus.  Have added user to dialout group. User is admin.  gSender still does not see it.  I know it's a permissions problem, just need help giving the correct permissions for a port that moves around.